# Multi-dimensional arrays, but I cannot retrieve data PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

More errors from my most recent project (posted about another thing earlier).

I've been struggling with this error for a few days now. PHP is not my main programming language, nor am I that great at it.

I'm aware that `mysql_*` should not be used, also.

Anyways. Here's the code snip.

```
                    <?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM events";
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                        $content = array();            

                        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
                        if ($num > 0) {
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                $content[$row['ID']] = $row;
                            }
                        }
                        if ($num > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($content)));?></th><th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($content as $tablerow): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $tablerow);?>
                            </td><td><div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Actions"><a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="#">New Session</a><a class="btn btn-success" role="button" href="#">Continue Latest</a><a class="btn btn-warning" role="button" href="#">Settings</a><?php echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' role='button' href='/manager/delete?id=".$row."'>Delete</a>"; ?>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
```

Sorry for derp formatting. Anyways.

I'm trying to get that `delete` button to link to `../manager/delete?id=x`, where x is the ID for the row. My database is formatted in the way where the ID is in a column labeled "ID". I'm trying to reference each of these rows by this ID... why is this not working?

I've also tried (in the place of `row`), `content[row['ID']]`, `content['ID']`, 'row['ID']`, with different case on the ID (uppercase/lowercase).

Comment: you're doing `as $tablerow` but referencing `$row` in `delete?id=".$row."` I could be wrong about this though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- wow. That was the only thing that I didn't try in debugging this. I'm hitting my head against the table now....

Comment: also `row['ID']` and `delete?id=".$row."` now one of those `id-ID`  needs changing - could be a mix of both.

Comment: wow, I'm left right out of the loop LMFHO!!! there's another answer. *Way to go Fred!* - I can take my hamster out for a walk now.

Answer (score 0):

Fred -ii- was correct in his above comment.

I had tried everything other than `$tablerow['ID']`.... now you know I guess.

Thank you for the help everyone. One of the dumbest things I've ever missed while debugging....

Comment: *"Thank you for the help everyone."* - Um... I was the "only" one. Shouldn't "I" have posted an answer? lol

Comment: or maybe you know of my multiple personalities ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha, I was thanking everyone who even looked. But thank you very much, your answer is the most correct.

Comment: I didn't put in an "answer" lol that's why I'm having a good chuckle here!

Answer (score 0):

he was partially correct, however i think your id is the key, so you might just reference the key so its a bit cleaner

```
<?php foreach ($content as $idKey => $tablerow): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $tablerow);?>
        </td><td><div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Actions"><a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="#">New Session</a><a class="btn btn-success" role="button" href="#">Continue Latest</a><a class="btn btn-warning" role="button" href="#">Settings</a><?php echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' role='button' href='/manager/delete?id=".$idKey."'>Delete</a>"; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```